# How to Enable HSTS in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, hsts

I want to enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on my Azure Function App.

I've added the HSTS configuration settings to the function app's host.json file based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=isolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings), but I am not getting the Strict-Transport-Security response header.

This is my host.json file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "api",
      "hsts": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "includeSubDomains": true,
        "maxAge": "365"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the function?

Comment: @MattEvans, I've tested it by calling the base URL of my function app. For example, `(curl -s -D- https://my-function-apps-url).Headers`. Additionally, I have sent HTTP requests to various functions, but I am not receiving the Strict-Transport-Security header.

Comment: Can you try it from a browser, and inspect the headers?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a .NET6 in process Azure Function App in Azure Portal.

- Then I added the **HSTS** code in `host.json` file as shown below.

**host.json**-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "api",
      "hsts": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "includeSubDomains": true,
        "maxAge": "365"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

[image]

After adding in this way, I am able to see **hsts** in the response header while invoking the function url. I am using  `curl -s -D- https://{functionApp_name}.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1` command.

[image]